# C# / Sql Server 2008 INSERT int value grows automatically to 1000000

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a strange problem recently that only occured one time in Sql Server 2008.

I work in a .net web application (C#) and use SqlCommand to access my Database and execute queries. My process is the following:

1. I have a view that get me the maximum number existing in a specific table:

   SELECT MAX(number) as MaxNumber
   FROM MyTable
2. I get this MaxNumber in a variable and, with this variable, I execute an insert in MyTable with the MaxNumber + 1. Like that, I always have the maximum number logged in MyTable

It worked well since that one time, a week ago, when, suddenly, I saw a MaxNumber that passed from 134200 to 1000000 !

I investigate my code and there is no way it could be the reason of that behavior. I also inspected the logs of the Web Server, no logs of bad Insert throwned.

I looked also into the logs of Sql Server I've found no logs of error...

What is suspicious is that the number passed from a "common" number (134200) to a "specific" number (1000000). Why 1000000 ? Why not 984216 or 1000256 ?

Is there someone that experienced the same problem ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT - 2014-12-23:**

I analyzed further the problem and it seems that it occurred when I restored a backup in my PreProd environment.

I explain: I have PreProd server where I have an Sql Server Instance (PreProd) and I have a Prod server where I also have an Sql Server Instance (Prod), which is backed up every day, on this same server.

When I want to test with effective datas, I restore the Prod backups on my PreProd databases:

```
RESTORE DATABASE PreProd
FROM DISK = '\\Prod\Backup\SQL\Prod.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Prod' TO 'E:\Bases\Data\PreProd.mdf',
MOVE 'Prod_log' TO 'E:\Bases\Data\PreProd.ldf',
REPLACE
```

The problem occurred the same day I restored my backup. The "1000000 row" appeared at the same moment of my restore, on my Prod database. Is there any possibility that it's linked ? Was the Prod server overwhelmed with the restore command executed from my PreProd server, and it, eventually, crashed an Insert request that occurred at the same moment ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Is that an identity column

Comment: does it happen if you restore the value to 134201?

Comment: I assume there is a record in MyTable for 1000000 and none for 134201 - 999999

Comment: @NoDisplayName : no, it's not an identity column

Comment: @faby : I will restore values from 134201 this afternoon

Comment: @MartinBrown : Yes, it's exactly that

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure you have seen all the code that may have been run, maybe have a search on the codebase for 1000000? Is it possible someone else may have inserted this row while testing something? Would they admit to it if you asked them? Could you have been hacked?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think is that maybe you are getting the maxValue with [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method without casting the result to a proper datatype

```
var max= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

and then

```
max= max+1;
```

Otherwise I saw that with your version of sqlServer you may receive incorrect values when using [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

refer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) for the bug fix, you should update to `SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1`

Comment: I read my view using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(). Then I reader my SqlDataReader (SqlDataReader.Read()) to get the first result, selecting the good field (SqlDataReader["MaxNumber"]).

Comment: you should use ExecuteScalar Method for that kind of query. It's just a suggestion

Comment: Given the max+1 method it does not look like @@IDENTITY is going to be the issue.